# MutableList<*> привести к MutableList<String>

Tags: kotlin

В интерфейсе описан метод:

```
fun setElements(items: MutableList<*>)
```

Реализую интерфейс:

```
var mLocalItems: MutableList<String>? = null
override fun setElements(items: MutableList<*>) {
    mLocalItems = items
}
```

Студия выдает мне type mismatch.

- Собственно вопрос в том, как items привести к mLocalItems?
- Можно ли использовать интерфейсы в Котлине без генериков? (ведь в Джаве мы можем объявить List list).

Answer (score 0):

Можно привести тип с помощью [оператора `as`](https://kotlinlang.org/docs/reference/typecasts.html#unsafe-cast-operator):

```
mLocalItems = items as MutableList<String>
```